# Mahout clustering: How to retrieve the name of a named vector

Tags: cluster-analysis, mahout

I want to cluster multiple documents using Mahout. The clustering works fine but I have no idea how to find out which documents are located in each cluster.

I read that you can use the option `--namedVector` when creating the sparse-files but where does it take the ID from and how can I retrieve this ID after the clustering is completed?

---

Right now I am doing the following steps:

I have a directory with a file for each document. The files are in the following format with the ID of the document as filename:

```
filename: documentID.txt

[TITLE]

[CONTENT]
```

I create a sparse directory with namedVectors using:

```
./mahout seqdirectory -i tmp/es-out -o tmp/es-out-seqdir -c UTF-8 -chunk 64 -xm sequential
./mahout seq2sparse -i tmp/es-out-seqdir -o tmp/es-out-sparse --maxDFPercent 85 --namedVector
```

Then I can cluster the results and create a dump:

```
./mahout kmeans -i tmp/es-out-sparse/tfidf-vectors -c tmp/es-kmeans-clusters -o tmp/es-kmeans -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure -x 10 -k 20 -ow --clustering
./mahout clusterdump -i tmp/es-kmeans/clusters-10-final -o tmp/clusterdump -d tmp/es-out-sparse/dictionary.file-0 -dt sequencefile -b 100 -n 20 --evaluate -dm org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure -sp 0 --pointsDir tmp/es-kmeans/clusteredPoints
```

The dump looks like this:

```
:VL-190{n=1 c=[1:3.407, 110:6.193, 2007:3.736, about:1.762, according:2.948, account:3.507, acting:6.
  Top Terms: 
    epa                                     =>  13.471728324890137
    mountaintop                             =>  11.364262580871582
    mine                                    =>  10.942587852478027

  Weight : [props - optional]:  Point:

[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. You can use the seqdumper to extract the cluster mapping:

```
./mahout seqdumper -i /tmp/es-kmeans/clusteredPoints/part-m-00000 -o /tmp/cluster-points.txt
```

Than you can use a regex to extract the mapping of the vector IDs to cluster IDs.

Answer (score 0):

k-means in Mahout is only a toy.

You can use it for howtos and tutorials, but for real use it is too slow, too limited, roo hard to use. (Also, k-means results are not half as good as people think... most of the time they are dogfood.)

**Benchmark** other tools, and you'll be surprised big time.

Comment: Ok, but choosing a different clustering algorithm should lead to the same problem, that I want to get the IDs of all documents in a cluster.

Comment: Not with a different, better tool. Mahout is just not very capable for clustering. It's built for recommender systems - that is what the developers had interest in. Nobody was ever really interested in clustering.

Comment: I understand that it is not the best tool for the job.

But just to get this clear. You are saying that there is no way to get the documents of my cluster using Mahout?

Comment: No. I just say I found it to be a dead tool, and suggest it may be **easier to use a better tool than to figure out the bugs and quirks of Mahout clustering**... of course you *can* get the document ids. Just just might need to understand and modify the source code of Mahout (go ahead - this is a *programming* ''web site, not a "how do I use tool xyz" website. A question like "how do I need to modify class xyz line 123 to output the document id would be more on topic)